# Laravel store uploaded image path with filename

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to store the uploaded users image's path in db.Here is my code in controller,

```
      $file = Input::file('pic');
      $img = Image::make($file);
      Response::make($img->encode('jpeg'));
      $filepath = $file->getPathName();
```

But the above code results,
 wrong path like **C:\xampp\tmp\phpA0C8.tmp**Bt I've uploaded image from my laravel public folder.I've tried plenty of codes but they doesn't work.How do I solve this?Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you using intervention?

Comment: Yeah,I'm using intervention

Comment: If you are using intervention, You can set the upload path before the image is uploaded so you can save that in the database as well. [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-image-upload-and-resize?page=1)

Comment: Can you pls give me an example code

Comment: Check [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-image-upload-and-resize/replies/57086)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a path with the file name.

```
    $FileName            = Input::file('pic')->getClientOriginalName();
    $FileDestinationPath = public_path('') .'/folder-name-in-public-folder/'.$FileName;
```

Or you can get it by using store method

```
$path = Input::file('pic')->store('folder-name');

return $path;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem

Comment: Thanks,But I just want to store the uploaded image path ,I don't need to move to folder.

Comment: Do you want to store URI or physical path?

Comment: Physical path to be stored in db

Comment: Then you will definitely get proper path in $FileDestinationPath just check it out

Comment: Thaks,It works- `$FileName            = Input::file('pic')->getClientOriginalName();
    $FileDestinationPath = public_path('') .'/folder-name-in-public-folder/'.$FileName;`

Comment: You can provide `'folder-name-in-public-folder'` as the argument to the `public_path()` function (without the directory separators - although I believe you'll still need the directory separator after that...). `$FileDestinationPath = public_path('folder-name-in-public-folder') . '/' . $FileName;`

Answer (score 1):

Use laravel file store method and hashname

```
public function fileUPload(Request $request){
    $file = $request->file('pic');
    $dir = '/my_images/';
    $file->store($dir, 'public_path'); //store images
    echo $filePath= $dir . $file->hashName();
}
```

//config/filesystems.php

```
return [

   ///....

    'disks' => [

        'public_path' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(),
        ],
    //...
    ],

];
```

Comment: Thanks,But it shows the below error ` 
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Driver [] is not supported. `

Comment: It shows the below result, `/my_images/C:\xampp\tmp\php4DB9.tmp`

Answer (score 0):

Use the store method

```
 $filepath = $request->file('pic')->store('pictures');
```

more [info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-uploads)

Place the code before the response

Comment: Thanks.But it shows the output of file path like this'"images/cXjiJxQckDVWx6DEYef9lbXWE8O9NTihp53zpJNj.jpeg"' I'm not using any encryption

Comment: laravel create a unique file name for you, if you want to rename your file use the saveAs, see the documentation link